# VLOOKUP with string returning #REF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following set up in Excel, and I am attempting to lookup the first column in the range A5:A7, and return column 8 (the rate) plus the custom rate.

This is the link to the current setup I have in Excel:

[image]

I am using the following thus far and it returns the #REF! error.

=G11+VLOOKUP(A11,$A$5:$A$7,8)

So for instance, to in row 11, I am trying to find the word Flash under the Type in the range A5:A7, and return the rate that it has (column #8 or H).

It should result in $0.26.

I am new to Excel, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase the range given to `VLOOKUP` to include **all** the columns containing data that you want to reference. In this case the range needs to include column 8, so it should be $A$5:$H$7 or wider.